# A riddle but there's an answer that is hard to find

Tags: riddle

> I'm one in one.
>
> I'm two in three.
>
> We are three.
>
> Who is four?

**What does this mean? It's backwards. So work backwards.**

Comment: The answer was not very hard to find...

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you made several typos in the text of the riddle, so I'm answering what I think you wanted to type instead. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I think the answer to

`Who is four?`

is

> <strike>eleven</strike> seventeen

because the numbers refer to

> the letter e, and there are four 'e's in <strike>eleven</strike> seventeen.

Backwards explanation of each line:

`We are three,`

> There are only two 'e's in 'three', but I have a feeling that there's some violation of basic rules of communication going on in here, and one should also count the 'e' in either 'we' or 'are'.

`I am two in a three`

> There are two 'e's in 'three'.

`I am one in one`

> There's one 'e' in 'e'.

**EDIT:** I used the wrong word for the answer. I corrected that.